# hook_menu drupal does not work on subdomain

Tags: drupal, module

My module has two files: twominutes.info, twominutes.module

**twominutes.info**

```
name = Two Minute Module
description = "Demonstration of how quickly you can build a single-page module."
package = Build a Module
core = 7.x
files[] = twominutes.module
```

**twominutes.module**

```
function twominutes_menu() {
  $items['twominutes-page'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'twominutes_page',
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
  return $items;
}

function twominutes_page() {
  return "Hello, world!";
}
```

When viewing on subdomain it does not work - returns a 404 page.

Subdomain is: http://sd0.caspian-host.ir/twominutes-page

Comment: Even when you are logged in as admin (privileges issue)? You cleared the cache after adding your hook_menu? Is hook_menu called at all (try writing out something from that function)?

Comment: yes, i did all the ways :(